# Default app engine regex for skip_files

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine

`google.appengine.api.appinfo.DEFAULT_SKIP_FILES` contain:

```
^(.*/)?((#.*#)|(.*~)|(.*\.py[co])|(.*/RCS/.*)|(\..*)|)$
```

Is that regex corrent?

It seems it doesn't match RCS/index.txt because of the first slash in `(.*/RCS/.*)`.

And what is the meaning of the last pipe character in the regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about the regex [doesn't match](http://regexr.com?320l5) the string `RCS/index.txt` because of the first slash.

Last pipe makes an *empty alternative* and causes to make the group **optional**. So, following two are equivalent:

```xml
^(.*/)?((#.*#)|(.*~)|(.*\.py[co])|(.*/RCS/.*)|(\..*)|)$
^(.*/)?((#.*#)|(.*~)|(.*\.py[co])|(.*/RCS/.*)|(\..*))?$
```